# How to disable the "Select Data source window in VBA"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file with macro-enabled that is used to upload the data from excel into a database. There's a button in excel to run this code. When I run the code, it has a window pop-up "Select Data Source". Does anyone how to prevent this from popping up.

Thank You

Sadly as a beginner I cannot provide the picture so I will explain.

When the button is clicked. A window is opened named "Select Data Source" with three options dBASE Files, Excel Files, MS Access Database. I need to select one of them and continue on. For me it's excel so I click this  and press okay. Then it has the option of allowing me to select the workbook.  Is there a way to pre-do this before so that I don't see this window.

The code is shown Below, which gives this problem.

```
Sub Collect_campaigns()
Dim qryCampaigns As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
qryCampaigns = "SELECT * FROM test.tbl_test;"
Worksheets("Campaigns").Visible = True

Sheets("Campaigns").Select
Range("A:F").Select
Selection.Clear
Range("A1").Select
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "ODBC;DSN=TEST_DATASOURCE;", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
.CommandText = qryCampaigns
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With
```

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Comment: I will add that above in a bit

Comment: Did I miss something that I get -2 now ? That's the best I can explain in words. This system wouldn't allow me to upload an image which I think need is not a good idea, as beginners find it hard to explain and plus it just makes the post long and visual representation is better.

Comment: @ArranRai, before running the macro, hit Alt+F11 on the keyboard, that brings up the Visual Basic window, where you can see the macro's code. You should search the code for "Select Data Source", then copy the segment that contains it and paste it below your question. Without that it is not possible for us to find out what the macro does in the background.

Comment: @ArranRai The window you see is caused by custom code that none of us here can see. If we COULD see that code, we could tell you how to adjust it so that "Workbook" is automatically selected and no window is opened. Since you are the only one with access to the workbook, you will need to find the code and paste it here so that people can help you. Following robotik's suggestion will help you do that. Right now this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: added above the code. Please have a look and tell me what can be the problem.

Comment: you can simplify & speed up the code by eliminating "Select"s. instead of `Sheets("Campaigns").Select
Range("A:F").Select
Selection.Clear
Range("A1").Select` you can go `Sheets("Campaigns").Range("A:F").Clear`

Comment: Also remove Application.ScreenUpdating = False  until you know how to add error handling to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
"ODBC;DSN=TEST_DATASOURCE;", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
```

As you can see in the code above, your macro refers to ODBC DataSource named TEST_DATASOURCE. I can only assume that you have copied this file from other computer, if so you also need to create same ODBC Datasource on your machine too.

If your machine is running Windows you should check "Control Panel-->Administrative Tools-->Data Sources(ODBC)".

Comment: The OP wasn't entirely clear, but I get the impression he said he got this dialog box when he ran it on his machine.  I know what you're getting at with your answer, but I don't think he's yet got to the point where he's deploying this on other machines -- could be wrong.  There are some holes in my understanding of his problem

Comment: I have replicated an issue on my machine, i created empty excel file with only macro code: "With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "ODBC;DSN=TEST_DATASOURCE;", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
.CommandText = qryCampaigns
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With"  and I get the same screen, so to get rid of it one needs to create proper ODBC Datasource and that's it. You can try to do it yourself, it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up window is a polite way of telling you that it cannot reconcile your datasource `"ODBC;DSN=TEST_DATASOURCE;"` with the available ODBC data sources.  Your minimialistic approach is a good one, I think -- not putting the entire connection string in but just the name.  It allows MS Query to fill in the blanks based on your ODBC connection settings).

Although less likely, it could also have something to do with the password, where the ODBC connection is rejecting the attempted use at the embedded password.  Since you said your data source is Excel, I'm going to put that into the 'unlikely' category...  unless your data source isn't really Excel and you were pulling our proverbial legs.

My recommendation would be to apply good programming practices:  cheat and be lazy

1. Record macro
2. Create the table as you would normally in Excel, Data->From Other Sources->MS Query (or whatever)
3. Stop the macro

Now run the macro code on a clean workbook -- with any luck it will run fine.  Then, strip out pieces of fluff code as you see fit and continue to re-test it until it breaks.